# Javascript: get constructor name when it contains a dot

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, namespaces

When I run the following code in the console:

```js
let Func1 = function () {};
let f1 = new Func1();

let Namespace = {};
Namespace.Func2 = function (a, b) {};
let f2 = new Namespace.Func2();

console.log(f1.constructor.name);
console.log(f2.constructor.name);
```

I get the following output:

```
Func1.      --> as expected
            --> empty string!
```

I was almost going to give up, but then I realised that, when typing just `f1` and `f2` in the console, this is the output:

```
> f1
  Func1 {}
> f2
  Namespace.Func2 {}
```

How does the console know that `f2` is an instance of `Namespace.Func2`?

So, there has to be a way of getting the constructor name as a string, given the instance object. Can anyone shed some light on this?

---

You can run `f2 instanceof Namespace.Func2` and it will return true, but I don't want to think that the console loops through every possible class.

There is a way to "alias" the constructor name: `Namespace.Func3 = function Func_Alias () {};`, but that's not what I want. I want to retrieve the original name, as shown in the console.

I am using Chrome. In Firefox you don't get the name of either function in the console.

Comment: Here Func2 is a key for Namespace Dict type and the function object assigned to Func2 has no name itself like an anonymous function. That's why you don't have `f2.constructor.name` because there's no `Func2.constructor.name` it's just `Function`

Comment: "*How does the console know that f2 is an instance of Namespace.Func2?*" - because it has access to the debugger api. (And FF has a different debugger, that's why you get different results there). "*So there has to be a way of getting the constructor name as a string, given the instance object.*" - no, there is not. "*I want to retrieve the original name*" - what for?

Comment: What for? To pass `this` to a logging function and have the name of the calling function in the logs. I will have to pass it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the specific behaviour defined as part of the javascript interpreter when dealing with assignation in variable declaration of an anonymous function definition.

```
let f1 = function(){}
```

Notice that if it doesn't happen if it is not an anonymous function. Or if you assigned a variable that contains already a reference to a funcion.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the case. If you do now `let f2 = new f1();`, `f2.constructor.name` will be `”f1”`.

Comment: I stated clearly that this is not the case if  "assigned a variable that contains already a reference to a funcion." This is exactly what the "new" does as it creates a new object. My example clearly mention function declaration on the right side of the declaration assignation.