# Nodejs how to get the prototype of a function like the debugger

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, constructor, prototype

In Nodejs, I am trying to get the prototype name of a function defined like:

```
AgreementSchema.statics.saveAgreement = function(){...}
```

When I check the Web-storm debugger, it can fetch the type of it and display it. I tried different things like prototype.constructor.name etc but since it is defined as an anonymous function it doesn't work.

You can check the debugger screenshot below, and see that "model.saveAgreement.prototype" is shown with "AgreementSchema.statics.saveAgreement".

[image]

Is there a way that I can get the name of this function as String like the debugger does?

Comment: No, this info is for the debugger only. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658510/javascript-debugging-in-chrome-object-name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668358/what-is-the-class-name-shown-in-chromes-debugger-based-on-can-it-be-controll https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727549/javascript-get-constructor-name-when-it-contains-a-dot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491766/vscode-debugger-with-typescript-what-determines-how-an-object-is-rendered

Comment: "*You can see that "model.saveAgreement.prototype" is shown with "AgreementSchema.statics.saveAgreement"*" - yes, but that's only because it thinks the prototype object is an "instance" of the `saveAgreement` "class". So that's not the "prototype name", it's the class name (or: the name of the function itself). Except of course that this function should never be used as a constructor, and it shouldn't even have a `.prototype`. Define it as a normal method, and it'll have a normal `.name`.

Comment: Wouldn't `AgreementSchema.statics.saveAgreement = function saveAgreement(){...}` work to solve that issue? It's an anonymous function, just de-anonymise it?

Comment: @somehinghere Well it would work for this one, but we have the same structure for our all schema object functions. So this is a general question